# How to convert list to DataFrame?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

My list has 51 columns. Here is a small extract:

```
[   airportResources.baggage_x  airportResources.arrivalTerminal_x  \
0                         NaN                                   1   

  schedule.serviceClasses_y status_y operationalTimes.actualDateTime_y  
0                       RJY        L                            421075  

[1 rows x 51 columns],    airportResources.baggage_x  airportResources.arrivalTerminal_x  \
0                         NaN                                   1   

  schedule.serviceClasses_y status_y operationalTimes.actualDateTime_y  
0                         Y        L                            421185  

[1 rows x 51 columns],   airportResources.baggage_x  airportResources.arrivalTerminal_x  \
0                         14                                   1   

  schedule.serviceClasses_y status_y operationalTimes.actualDateTime_y  
0                      RFJY        L                            424447  

[1 rows x 51 columns]]
```

Then I try to convert this list to the DataFrame as follows:

```
data = np.concatenate ([z[51:] for z in flights]) 
data = data.reshape(-1, 51)
flights = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=flights[0][:51])
```

And then the following error message appears:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (51, 0), indices imply (1, 0)
```

The problem occurs at this line of code:

```
flights = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=flights[0][:51])
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal representative input, please?

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel: What do you mean? I provided an extract from flights. please let me know what exactly should I add? There is quite lot of data.

Comment: i mean the data you provide are unusable. Can you provide on the contrary a small reproducible sample of your data ? (not a list with 10 000 elements but 5 , 6 to 12 elements)

Comment: flights[0][:51] ... This is correctly indexed? I mean, can you print that before you do the last sentence?

Comment: @user3926962: When I do "print flights[0][:51]", I see the output given in the thread.

Comment: @user3926962: It looks like I'm not properly creating "data"

Comment: Oh ok, I thought that it was wrong but it isn't...  what's the resulting shape that you want to have in data?